# Webfaction illegal in EU due to judgment in Case c-311/18?

Tags: hosting, webfaction

Our data protection officer, in relation to the judgment c-311/18 (https://edpb.europa.eu/news/news/2020/statement-court-justice-european-union-judgment-case-c-31118-data-protection_pl), questioned the possibility of storing personal data on Webfaction's machines:( Unfortunately their DATA PROCESSING ADDENDUM in point 9 - Transfers of Personal Data (https://www.webfaction.com/local_media/WebFactionDPA.pdf) mentions the possibility of transferring data to the US under the EU-US Privacy Shield Frameworks, which was challenged by the aforementioned judgment.

In the opinion of our DPO, it is not possible to use the webfaction services until this provision is changed. Do any of you also have this problem? Maybe a different legal opinion?

Answer (score 0):

Not a good answer, but I'll give it anyway.

Before being acquired, I believe that Webfaction was based in the UK, and you could request servers in Europe. I don't know whether this is still true or relevant.

You might want to consider Opalstack as an alternative. It's a lot of what Webfaction used to be pre-aquisition, and I believe has servers in Europe. I've been exploring switching to them, and have been happy so far. However, I believe that their ownership is technically in the United States.

I am not a lawyer, an expert, or anyone who can offer an opinion on this. I'm just offering some additional information and options for you to consider.